# NumberFormatException when tokenizing a string and converting to an integer

Tags: java, token, bufferedreader, numberformatexception, stringtokenizer

I am trying to read in a text file and from that file, find the number of rows and columns. I decided to do this by tokenizing the input string and then convert it into an integer in order to find rows and columns. When I compile, I get a "java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString". Any explanation of why this problem may be caused will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
BufferedReader inF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/Users/marco/Desktop/5ele.txt")));
    String s = "";

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int z = 0;

    while((s = inF.readLine()) != null){  

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ""); 
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            int convertedToInt = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());   //this is where the problem occurs

            if (z == 0) {
                row = convertedToInt;
            } else if (z == 1) {
                col = convertedToInt;
            }

            z++;
        }
    }
```

- I also linked an example of the text file:
  [Sample Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pccxn.png)
- Note that each character whether it is a period or a letter can be imagined as being a single cell in a table if you will
- The output that I am looking for in the text file sample is 3 rows and 10 columns.

Comment: You're parsing the whole line as an input to `Integer.parseInt()` since you are using `new StringTokenizer(s, "");`, in which the delimiter is an empty string.

Comment: How should I fix this problem?

Comment: How exactly to you mean to parse this input to integers? Can you edit your question with the parsed result for the sample input you provided?

Comment: What your original file looks like? Show several lines of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up the StringTokenizer with no delimiters (empty string in constructor). This means it can't split your line into tokens.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you need to replace the StringTokenizer code (everything after `while((s = inF.readLine()) != null){`) with

```
  z++;
  col = s.length()
}
row = z;
```

This uses z to count the rows looped over, and takes the column count from string length.

Comment: You're welcome; please mark this answer accepted. Of course, it's sloppy to set `col` over and over again as I've done; you should check that `s.length()` always has the same value.